# Chaining CSS animations and retain values between animations

Tags: html, css, animation

**Fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/gkzqLfxa/1/**

I'm trying to chain CSS animations such that I can write generic animations that don't need to have prior knowledge of the values that happened before them.

For example:

`MyDiv` has an animation that animates its `opacity` from `0` to `SomeValue`. Then a second animation fades out, from `SomeValue` to `0`. Currently, I have to write an animation to fade in to `0.5`, then another animation that fades out from `0.5` to `0`.

I attempted to do this by not putting in the `opacity` property in the `0%` keyframe, like so:

```
@keyframes fadeinhalf
{
  0% { opacity: 0; }
  100% { opacity: 0.5; }
}

@keyframes fadeinfull
{
  0% { opacity: 0; }
  100% { opacity: 1; }
}

@keyframes fadeout
{
  0% {
  }

  100%{
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

However, when I run this, with `fadeinhalf` first, then `fadeout` second, there is a hitch at the 0% keyframe of `fadeout` where it goes back to `opacity: 1;`.

I would rather have something where I can write that first animation custom, but the fade out animation could be generic, and fade out from any opacity to `0`. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
-webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
```

will retain the state of the final keyframe, though I've not used it for this exact application…

EDIT: possible alternative solution

You may need to use the jQuery Keyframes library (http://keyframes.github.io/jQuery.Keyframes/)

and do something like:

```
var supportedFlag = $.keyframe.isSupported();

var setOpacity = 0.5;

function setKeyFrame(data) {
    var setOpacity = data;
    $.keyframe.define([{
        name: 'magic',
        '0%': {'opacity': 0},
        '100%': {'opacity': setOpacity}
    }]);
};

$(document).ready(function() {

    setKeyFrame(1);

    $('#target-element').playKeyframe(
      'magic 1s linear 0s infinite normal forwards',
      complete
    );

});
```